# Absurd finder search results on my mac

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight, search

I have MS Teams installed on my MacBook pro. So I set to find it and tried using finder. However, I got the following search results:[image]

All the initial search results have no similarity in their names with Microsoft teams. After scrolling down for a while do I see teams finally. How do I configure the settings to fix my search results. Also, surprisingly the same problem does not occur with spotlight search. Kindly help. to

Comment: Tried making the search find **both** words not just one or the other?

Comment: I was about to make a reply essentially saying 'nonsense' and/or 'you don't know how to use Finder search'.  But I can sometimes reproduce what you see but with Microsoft Word (I don't have Teams).  Not consistently. I will investigate more later or tomorrow.

Comment: With the search you have shown with the issue: Save the search (button near top right) to a .savedSearch file (just save it on your desktop or somewhere handy). In Finder go to the Desktop and do a Get Info on the savedSearch file.  What is in the Query? Here is a well behaved search for Microsoft Excel: ((** = "microsoft excel*"cdwt) && (kMDItemDisplayName = "Microsoft Excel"cd)).  But I have a very wrong query for Microsoft Word.